# Use the same Google api keys across different platforms

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I am using some Google Api's for which I have Google Api Keys.

Im developing on android, ios and web.

Should I use the same keys on all 3 formats - or should I create a separate project in the google console and use a separate key for each?

Will I get more api quota uses if i split it into 3 projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [recommends that you restrict your API keys](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en). Since each API key can only have a single type of restriction, it is best that you create one key per platform. That way, you can have a web key with referrer restrictions and Android and iOS key each with app restrictions.

In most cases, it's probably best to create a single project to contain all of your keys. It ensures that configurations are applied uniformly applied and all API traffic can be viewed on a single dashboard. For other considerations, especially around permissions, take a look at [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview).